# Compiled archive with ar, compiles manually, ld does not find

Tags: c++, g++, ld

I have compiled a hello world library to test my build setup:

```
// hw.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include"hw.h"

void hw(){ std::cout << "hw"<<std::endl; }

// hw.h
void hw();

// main.cpp
#include"hw.h"
int main(int argv, char ** argc){
  hw();
  return 0;
}

// BUILD COMMAND (ommitting proj directories, replacing with '.')
g++ -I. -o hw.o hw.cpp

// Archive Command
ar -rcs hw.a hw.o

// Compile (works as expected)
g++ -I. -o hw main.cpp hw.a

// Compile with ld
g++ -I. -L. -o hw main.cpp -lhw
```

And the result is failure.  I have tried absolute paths, looked at ld documentation; and in general burnt time trying to figure out this issue.

What could be going on here?

Exact error code:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhw
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Could you please post your exact error message, too? Does the ld-error appear while compiling (last line) or when trying to execute the program? EDIT: I'm not sure, but I think, that your library should be named libhw.a

Comment: @itpdg posted exact error code.  And have never run into this issue before.  This amounts to a diagnostic question because it seems like nothing is wrong here...

Comment: As I thought. I tried your code out and got the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your error message, but after trying your code myself, I think that your problem is that ld cannot find your library. Libraries have to be named with the prefix `lib`. Rename `hw.a` to `libhw.a` and it should work.

Comment: I have just now checked this unfortunately... will double check

Comment: AH! Got it: have to drop the lib. So, if I name it "libhw" I have to link as "hw" -- must have just made this correction subconciously in the past, as I do this all the time haha